# Electron can't recieve Notification

Tags: javascript, electron

I tried to follow the tutorial on [this website](https://coursetro.com/posts/code/123/Electron-Desktop-Notifications-Tutorial), but after I did it I was unable to receive notifications as the final result of the tutorial

This is the code that I write:

```js
const electron      = require('electron');
const path          = require('path');
const BrowserWindow = electron.remote.BrowserWindow;
const axios         = require('axios');
const ipc           = electron.ipcRenderer;

const notifyBtn = document.getElementById('notifyBtn');
let price       = document.querySelector('h1');
let targetPrice = document.getElementById('targetPrice');
let targetPriceVal;

const notification = {
  title: 'BTC Alert',
  body : 'BTC just beat your target price!'
};

function getBTC() {
  axios.get('https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemulti?fsyms=BTC&tsyms=USD')
       .then(res => {
         const cryptos   = res.data.BTC.USD;
         price.innerHTML = '$' + cryptos.toLocaleString('en');
         if (targetPrice.innerHTML !== '' && targetPriceVal < res.data.BTC.USD) {
           const myNotification = new Notification(notification.title, notification);
           console.log(notification.title)
         }
       })
}

getBTC();
setInterval(function () {
  getBTC();
}, 10000);
```

The expectation that I want is: when the response results exceed my target value, I will get a notification.

I have tried using `console.log()` and it works well. But not with Notifications.

I tried to change `new window.Notification(...)` with `new Notification(...)` but same as well

Comment: In the tutorial you linked they show `new window.Notification(...)` but you do `new Notification(...)`, could this make a difference?

Comment: both of them didn't working as well.

Comment: https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/notifications#windows - See the caveats for this is development mode

Comment: Electron notifications are OS specific, which OS are you working on?

Comment: @junvar I'm working with windows 10 64bit